# Read file inside a function and contents must be available in the parameter passed using C

Tags: c

I'm trying to read a file inside a function and want it's contents in a parameter passed to the function after it returns.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    char dest[10000];
    copyString(dest);
    printf("%s", dest);
}

copyString(outStr)
char *outStr;
{
    char * buffer = 0;
    long length;
    FILE * f = fopen ("file.txt", "rb");

    if (f)
    {
        fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
        length = ftell (f);
        fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        buffer = (char *)malloc (length);
        if (buffer)
        {
            fread (buffer, 1, length, f);
        }
        fclose (f);
    }
    strcpy(outStr, buffer);
}
```

When I try the above it doesn't print anything. What is wrong in my code? Please help. I want dest to have the contents of the file in the main function.

Comment: Firstly, do the strcpy in copyString() only when the fopen() is success. Otherwise, return an error code and check that error code in the main() function before calling printf(). Secondly, initialize both buffers dest and buffer using functions such as memset(dest,0,sizeof(dest)).

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, curious.

It works for me.  I have two suggestions.

Make you sure your file.txt is in the same directory.

You might add an "else" clause to the if (f) condition, and say perror("open") in the else.

Also, make your file is small.  (Say just one line to start with).  You aren't testing for buffer overflow on the strcpy.  You should use strncpy instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't terminate your `buffer` with a null character, `'\0'`. The `str*` functions from `<string.h>` operate on null-terminated strings.

You open the file i binary mode, `"rb"`. If your data is binary it is likely to contain zeros, and printing will stop there. (If you are reading binary data, consider using `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` from `<stdint.h>` instead of `char`, which may ba signed.)

If you know the length of the buffer (which you do), you can use `memcpy` to copy the buffer.

You don't free `buffer`. There really is no need to allocate a local buffer and then copy to the output. You can read to the passed buffer directly. in any case you should make sure that the file contents fit into the buffer, possibly by passing the buffer dimension as second parameter.

The function would also be more useful if it returned the number of characters in buffer. (Or the characters that would be in the buffer had the bufer been big enough, `snprintf` style.)

And please, this is 2015: Don't use K&R style function signatures.

Comment: I agree with you not using K&R style function signatures, but it doesn't hurt this way either. GNU also seems neutral:
https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Standard-C.html#Standard-C